# c++: Can I overload operator[][]?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is a general question about operator overloading in cpp.
Is there a way to overload operator[][] ?

I want to do this because I want to implement a Matrix class, where the user can do matrix[a][b] and access the element in that position.

My friend told me to represent the matrix like this:

```
vector<vector<T>>
```

And in the constructor I would initialize it like this:

```
Matrix(int row, int col): vector<vector<T>>(row, vector<T>(col)) {}
```

Can someone please explain what the constructor is doing?
And how would I implement accessing a specific element in my Matrix, so: matrix[a][b] = c

Edit:
Seems like the operator[][] works fine, so i can do matrix[a][b] and access the element there. 
Why is this?

Edit 2: Thanks for the suggestions to use () but according to the instructions, it needs to be able to work on this code:
[image]

Comment: You do it by arranging for the result of `operator[]` to return a *proxy object*, which itself has an `operator[]` overload which yields the value. If you're smart about it the proxy object will not value copy the elements. Your friend's advice will get you off the ground but using `std::vector<str::vector<T>>` is not a natural representation as it models a jagged edge if you get my meaning (the rows can differ in length). Personally I use BLAS, and live with `(x, y)` for yielding a value.

Comment: Some people also like to use `operator()` , because you can pass two parameters. Would be for example `Martix m; m(0, 0) = 4;`. Secondly: `vector<vector<T>>` is also rather inefficent, storing data in a 1D-vector is faster.

Comment: Maybe create a template and then use `std::array<std::array<T, N>, M>` instead of `vector`

Comment: Judging by your code your Matrix class inherits from vector. That is why the vector [] works on your class. So it seems you don't need to overload [] at all.

Comment: This code `Matrix(int row, int col): vector<vector<T>>(row, vector<T>(col)) {}` creates vec tor is size `row` where each element of that vector is another vector of size `col`. A 2D vector in other words.

Comment: ok i understand, Thank you!!

Comment: There is no `operator[][]`. When you see `m[0][1]` there are **two** index operators involved. `m[0]` operates on `m` and returns something that has its own `operator[]`, and that's what the `[1]` is applied to.

Comment: Incredible good question!